# Marketing cloud: determine number of automation runs by year through system table queries?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a use case where I would like to know the number of automations in marketing cloud that have been run within a given year. Is there a way that I can query this data from a system table within Marketing cloud ?

As a higher level topic, do we have access to system tables in Marketing Cloud (e.g. ability to query JOB, AUTOMATION, JOURNEY, etc.. ) system tables ?

thanks/

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5 Take a look at the help documentation on available system views.

Answer (score 0):

Data Extensions in SFMC are equivalent to database tables. Those can include any columns that suit your requirements.

The Data Views (System Data Views), are read-only tables of Subscriber and Subscriber activity data.

The schemas for those are found on the Query Activity page.

Query Activities can only do SQL Select statements and add/update/append another Data Extension.

If you're looking for some syntax help, SFMC Query Activities follow Microsoft Transact-SQL (T-SQL) conventions (with a few exceptions).

Comment: Thanks KWo ! So in order to extract the number of times an automation has been run in Marketing Cloud ? How would I go about getting this data as I don't think it's available in the System Data Views.